# str_replace PHP don't work

Tags: php

i'm writing this code:

```
$response = "PARCHEGGIO BASILE (Cap.) – Via E. Basile – Cavalcavia Brasa - V.le Regione Siciliana - V. Villagrazia (Barone Scala) – V. Emily Balch - V. Villagrazia - V. dell’Usignolo - V. dell’Allodola - V.le Regione Siciliana - VIA DEL LEVRIERE (Bonagia) (capolinea di transito) - V.dell’ Antilope - V. dell’ Ermellino - V.le Regione Siciliana - V. dell’Allodola - V. dell’Usignolo - V. Villagrazia - V.le Regione Siciliana – svincolo Brasa - Via E. Basile - PARCHEGGIO BASILE (Cap.)";
$response =  str_replace( " – " , "@" , $response );
echo $response;
```

But the result is:

```
PARCHEGGIO BASILE (Cap.)@Via E. Basile@Cavalcavia Brasa - V.le Regione Siciliana - V. Villagrazia (Barone Scala)@V. Emily Balch - V. Villagrazia - V. dellâ€™Usignolo - V. dellâ€™Allodola - V.le Regione Siciliana - VIA DEL LEVRIERE (Bonagia) (capolinea di transito) - V.dellâ€™ Antilope - V. dellâ€™ Ermellino - V.le Regione Siciliana - V. dellâ€™Allodola - V. dellâ€™Usignolo - V. Villagrazia - V.le Regione Siciliana@svincolo Brasa - Via E. Basile - PARCHEGGIO BASILE (Cap.)
```

then, the str_replace don't function.. where i'm wrong?

Comment: `str_replace([' – ', ' - '], "@"…`

Answer (score 2):

They are different characters, that have `0x2d` and `0xe28093` (encoded as UTF-8) codes accordingly.

If you look carefully you can even see that they are of different length.

So, php just does what you instructed it to: it tries to replace a substring, and as soon as there is no entry in the source string - it lefts it untouched.

To replace all `-` you just use `-` character in your `str_replace` call instead of `–`

Useful links:

- http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2013/index.htm
- http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2d/index.htm

Answer (score 0):

Your sting was ill formatted, use this str_replace instead

```
$response = str_replace([' – ', ' - '], "@", $response);
```

Because the previous string included the `0x2d` or **–** as well as `0xe28093` or **-**, different unicode characters.

Comment: "different UTF-8 encoded characters" --- you would say "different unicode characters", since `UTF-8` is just *encoding*.

Comment: There you go, happy :P